# Installing FreeIPA with DNS -- NetworkError: cannot connect to 'ldap://labipa.example.com:389'

Tags: ldap, freeipa

Environment I'm using:

```
Red Hat Enterprise Linux 7.4
Virtualbox
```

I've installed all the required packages:

```
yum -y install ipa-server bind-dyndb-ldap ipa-server-dns
```

Added the following in my /etc/hosts:

```
192.168.1.1      labipa.example.com labipa
```

Install FreeIPA with DNS:

```
ipa-server-install --setup-dns --allow-zone-overlap

Server host name: labipa.example.com
Directory Manager password: ~~password~~
IPA admin password: ~~password~~
Enter IP address for a DNS forwarder: 8.8.8.8
Do you want to search for missing reverse zones? yes

[37/45]: initializing group membership
[error] NetworkError: cannot connect to 'ldap://labipa.example.com:389': 
ipa.ipapython.install.cli.install_tool(CompatServerMasterInstall): ERROR    cannot connect to 
'ldap://labipa.example.com:389': 
ipa.ipapython.install.cli.install_tool(CompatServerMasterInstall): ERROR    The ipa-server-install command 
failed. See /var/log/ipaserver-install.log for more information
```

Steps I've tried to fix:

```
firewall-cmd --permanent --add-service=ldap
firewall-cmd --reload
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The installation asks you for a DNS forwarder, which it presumably then uses to resolve any DNS lookups.

Because you've specified 8.8.8.8, it won't be able to work out that labipa.example.com points to your machine.

You can install something like dnsmasq, and have it read your /etc/hosts entry, and then tell the freeipa installer to use 127.0.0.1 as your DNS forwarder.

[Here](https://access.redhat.com/solutions/46767) is a RedHat guide on doing exactly this. It requires a RedHat support account (but you are using RedHat, so probably have an account). There is a [similar](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/374674/making-host-v-hostname-command-work-for-centos-7/374680#374680) solution on stackexchange too

Comment: So, it got stuck on `Done configuring directory server (dirsrv).`

Throwing some python error messages.

I ended up switching to CentOS 7 and it worked!  Go figure.  I just wanted to say thanks for all your help, since your answer did get me past that stage on Red Hat, but it unfortunately got stuck on a later part in the `ipa-server-install`.