# NetworkError: cannot connect to 'ldap://ipa.myserver.net:389' during install of FreeIPA

Tags: nginx, centos7, port, freeipa

**Problem**: When trying to install FreeIPA (Version 4.6.5) the installation breaks when trying to connect to the ldap server:

```
  [36/44]: adding entries for topology management
  [37/44]: initializing group membership
  [error] NetworkError: cannot connect to 'ldap://ipa.myserver.net:389':
```

Why is this happening to me and how can I solve this?

**Setup/Details**: I have a Cent OS 7 server (as a VM at Hetzner hosting) that is running a Nextcloud and a Matrix-Synapse. Also, I have nginx and firewalld running.

Also, my DNS record at my domain provide (inwx.de) points to my server-IP (and nginx serves the standard page when trying to access it via http).

Previously I installed the required packages (bind-utils, ipa-server, ipa-server-dns) and also opened ports on firewalld:

```
firewall-cmd --permanent --add-port={80/tcp,443/tcp,389/tcp,636/tcp,88/tcp,464/tcp,53/tcp,88/udp,464/udp,53/udp,123/udp}
```

My hostname is set to ipa.myserver.net - which I also provided during install for hostname, domain name and realm name. As DNS forwarders I set 8.8.8.8 and 8.8.4.4

For further install details see:
https://pastebin.com/FWMMRips

**Own thoughts:** I asusme something is blocking the request, as the initial setup-steps seem to work fine. But firewalld should let it through.
I was wondering if I have to tell nginx to also redirect traffic, but my mediocre server-block try with proxy_pass ldap://localhost:389; is not accepted.. 
Could that be something / how could I explore this issue further?

I wouldn't think [that the DNS cannot be resolved](https://serverfault.com/questions/898755/installing-freeipa-with-dns-networkerror-cannot-connect-to-ldap-labipa-ex) as I can reach the server via ipa.myserver.net.

Comment: usually the first dns is your own host not any public resolver

Comment: @djdomi thank you for that info! also with my host dns server-ips it's not working (I also turned of nginx and firewalld to try, still same problem..)